# Indicate Route Name in Html.Action helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to show routeName somehow in Html.Action
Something like this

```
Html.Action("Languages", "UIHelper", new {routeName="Default"});
```

Currently my application has many areas, and `Html.Action` is used in main Layout. When I redirect user to area page then my `Html.Action` could not find action/controller because mvc try to find it in  current (redirected) area

Comment: In your example, you aren't specifying the area, yet you mention areas in your question. Is that just an oversimplification in your example?

Comment: Couldn't you use RouteLink instead or extend your Html.Action to have that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Html.Action()` extension method that would make a use of a route name. Of course, you can go and create your own extension method that suits your needs, which I recommend doing anyway as a good exercise, but in your case solution might be much simpler.

By default, all routes use the current area for matching. You can override area by providing Area parameter, like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyLink",  "MyAction", new {Area = "MyArea" });
```

In your case, you want to use a controller in the root area, which is simply represented as a blank string. So all you need to do is:

```
@Html.Action("Languages", "UIHelper", new { Area = "" });
```

Comment: Second approach feets my expectations. Thank you @Jacek